# C-style comments in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to configure VS Code to use C-style comments (/**/) instead of C++ style ones (//) for C code only? My Gooogle-fu might be weak, but I haven't found any useful solution to it so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the line or lines then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually redefine it entirely to your liking, but it will require some fiddling with the **package.json** of the C/C++ extension.
This file will probably be located (at least on my Ubuntu it is) in ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-YOUR_VERSION_NUMBER. So open it

```
code ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-YOUR_VERSION_NUMBER/package.json
```

in terminal.
In this file you need to locate an object named "contributes".
Within this object you'll need to create an array called "languages" and add a language object:

```
"languages": [
    {
        "id": "c",
        "extensions": [
            ".c", ".h"
        ],
        "configuration": "./my-c-configuration.json"
    }
]
```

now the path in the configuration property needs to point to another .json file in which you will add the new definition for the comment command:
(in the "my-c-configuration.json" file, created in the same directory)

```
{
  "comments": {
    "lineComment": [ "/*", "*/" ],
    "blockComment": [ "/*", "*/" ]
  }
}
```

Save both files, reopen the VSCode, and that's all.

Answer (score 2):

[image: VS-Code Keyboard Shortcuts]

It's July, 2020 and latest vs code stable version is **Version 1.47.**
**Toggle block comment shortcut is : Shift+Alt+A.**
**Official Source** : [VS-Code Keyboard Shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Was this changed ? 
To me, it works with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.